# How to access Digital I/O using USB

Tags: c#, c++, c, vb.net, usb

How to access Digital I/O using USB using C or C++  or Vb.net Or C#.net?

Comment: What digital I/O? USB itself is a serial bus, it's not like a parallel port where you can just set pins randomly. USB talks to devices; you need a device that features digital I/O channels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use the [Velleman K8055 USB EXPERIMENT INTERFACE BOARD](http://www.vellemanusa.com/us/enu/product/view/?id=500349)

It is simple to program for, and has several inputs and outputs

I got one from [Maplin](http://www.maplin.co.uk/Module.aspx?ModuleNo=42857) for less than £30

Answer (score 2):

Easiest solution is possibly a USB-to-RS232 convertor. They're cheap commodity products, supported on most OS'es, and trivial to access as SerialPort objects. The physical side is a simple 5V, low-speed, low pincount interface suitable for both input and output.

Answer (score 1):

You can find more information here: http://www.beyondlogic.org/

Answer (score 1):

If you want to write/read directly to/from USB device, in Windows you can easily use function CreateFile with param lpFileName as special device name.
Example:

```
HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(
"\\\\.\\X:", //X - is your USB device letter
GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
FILE_SHARE_READ, //for example READ
NULL,
OPEN_EXISTING,
FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
NULL
);
```

Next you can work with your device as with normal file.
More information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363858%28VS.85%29.aspx)