# USB Big Red Button - How do I receive input in a C/C++/Java/C# program?

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, usb

I currently bought a USB Big Red Button:
http://www.dreamcheeky.com/big-red-button

It comes with pre-made software which comes with built-in functions that do stuff
when I use the button. However I can't customize it on Windows.

I simply want to be able to have a program that:

- Detects all USB devices connected to my computer to determine which
  one is my "Red Button" USB device
- With the Red Button USB device now selected in the program, determine when an input comes in:

  - User flips the lid of the button up
  - User flips the lid of the button down
  - User pressed the button
  - User released the button

And obviously on each of those events, execute a specific command I wish to do

(ie: printf("hello world"); )

How would I achieve this? Is there a known library I can use that can receive inputs from a USB device like this?

I've looked everywhere and I can't find one that's specific for windows.

Comment: I'd start [here](http://www.libusb.org/). It's cross-platform.

Comment: Some interesting stuff: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1345425/how-to-access-digital-i-o-using-usb?rq=1

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?